# Походження слова "кін"

Tags: етимологія, from-latin

> [КІН](http://sum.in.ua/s/kin) – cпеціальний майданчик, на якому показують вистави; сцена.

Яке походження даного слова? Чи воно, так само як і "сцена", походить від латинського `scaena`? І як це походження пов'язане з іншим значенням слова: "кін – місце, куди кладуть ставку в азартній грі"?

Answer (score 1):

Походження  слова **кін** знаходимо в Етимологічному словнику т.2, с.446-447:
[image]

[image]

Отже, слово **кін** пов'язане з іншим значенням слова: "кін – місце, куди кладуть ставку в азартній грі"?